# I'm looking to create a macro that automatically converts some data, but the conversion is difficult

Tags: excel, vba

I need to convert some Excel data regularly and it's laborious. As such, I'm looking to write a macro that converts some data, but the conversion itself is cumbersome and I'm not sure if it lends itself to automation.

I did try and put some Excel on, but I don't think I have the posts made to do it justice, so I'll try and make it easy.

Each row has a cost centre on, who can authorise on it, and up to how much in columns. So there are limit columns, let's call them 'Up to 50', 'Up to 100', 'Up to 200', 'Up to 500' and '501+'.

I've been asked to change it so that each name would be a separate row. This would mean every cost centre would gain rows for each approval level (100, 200, 500 etc).

This means the macro would need to automatically create new rows under each current row, copy some of the information and ultimately reduce the number of columns to only have one value.

I have mocked up an image that shows what I mean. Any one any ideas?

[image: Example]

Comment: You need to provide the code you have tried, and clearly explain what error you are getting from what line.

Comment: Google on "Excel depivot" (or "depivot") - eg: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+depivot+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: Andrew, it looks as though you are new here.  If the answer below is helpful, you should mark it as the selected answer.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.  Be sure to change the third line of the sub-procedure to indicate the cell where your table of data starts and that there is a blank column to the right of the data and a blank row below.

```
Sub convert_data()
    Dim cell As Range
    'begin by setting the "cell" variable to the upper left corner of the data
    Set cell = ActiveSheet.Range("a2")
    
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim colCount As Integer
    Dim firstRow As Long
    
    firstRow = cell.Row
    colCount = cell.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
    Set cell = cell.Offset(cell.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1)
    Do While cell.Row >= firstRow
        For x = colCount - 1 To 2 Step -1
            If cell.Offset(0, x).Value > "" Then
                cell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
                cell.Offset(1).Value = cell.Value
                cell.Offset(1, 1).Value = cell.Offset(0, x).Value
                cell.Offset(0, x).Value = ""
            End If
        Next
        Set cell = cell.Offset(-1)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: @Andrew, welcome to Stack Overflow.  If this answer was helpful, you should mark it as the accepted answer